# Bind9 Response Policy Zone (RPZ), does not work on clients - Ignore is my first post and It is off topic sorry

Tags: dns, bind9

On my *single* DNS server, **bind9** (**version 9.11.5-P4-5.1**), I have configured a *Response Policy Zone (RPZ)* to block certain domains. The IP of the DNS server is **192.168.1.5**

Now I am going to put the relevant parts to the configuration of the different files and commands:

On the server:

In **/etc/bind/named.conf.options**

```
acl trusted {
    localhost; # this server
    192.168.1.0/24; #my net
}
```

Also

```
// Only allows trusted client to use the service
allow-query { trusted; };

forwarders {
    The IP of the NS1 of IPS#1;
    The IP of the NS2 of IPS#1;
    The IP of the NS1 of IPS#2;
    The IP of the NS2 of IPS#2;
    8.8.8.8;
    8.8.4.4;
    1.1.1.1;
};
```

And also

```
    // For Ad-Blocking/Blacklisting/Whitelisting
    response-policy {
        zone "rpz.blacklist";
        zone "office.local" policy passthru;
        zone "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa" policy passthru;
    };
```

In **/etc/bind/named.conf.local**

```
  zone "rpz.blacklist" {
      typemaster;
      file "/etc/bind/zones/rpz.blacklist.db";
      allow-query { trusted; };
      allow-transfer { localhost; };
  };
```

And finally in **/etc/bind/zones/rpz.blacklist.db**

```
  ; BIND reverse data file for empty rfc1918 zone
  ;
  ; DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is used for multiple zones.
  ; Instead, copy it, edit named.conf, and use that copy.
  ;
  $TTL 86400
  @ IN SOA localhost. root.localhost. (
  1     ; Serial
  604800; Refresh
  86400; Retry
  2419200; expire
  86400); Negative Cache TTL
  ;

  @ IN NS localhost.

  ;.:#====================#:.
  ; Blacklist Domains
  ;.:#====================#:.

  ads2000.hw.net IN A 127.0.0.1
```

There are more domains but I leave one only for the example.

The commands [**named-checkconf**] and [**named-checkconf "rpz.blacklist" /etc/bind/zones/rpz.blacklist.db**] return OK and the service starts successfully

Now if I ping ads2000.hw.net from the same server **it works fine**

```
  ping -c 5 ads2000.hw.net
  PING ads2000.hw.net (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
  64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.037 ms
  64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.037 ms
  64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.037 ms
  64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.201 ms
  64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.034 ms

  --- ads2000.hw.net ping statistics ---
  5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 105ms
  rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.034/0.069/0.201/0.066ms
```

Now if I do it from a linux client, **it does not** :

```
  ping -c 5 ads2000.hw.net
  PING ads2000.hw.net (65.8.181.28) 56(84) bytes of data.
    64 bytes from server-65-8-181-28.mia3.r.cloudfront.net (65.8.181.28): icmp_seq=1 ttl=246 time=131 ms
    64 bytes from server-65-8-181-28.mia3.r.cloudfront.net (65.8.181.28): icmp_seq=2 ttl=246 time=131 ms
    64 bytes from server-65-8-181-28.mia3.r.cloudfront.net (65.8.181.28): icmp_seq=3 ttl=246 time=131 ms
    64 bytes from server-65-8-181-28.mia3.r.cloudfront.net (65.8.181.28): icmp_seq=4 ttl=246 time=131 ms
    64 bytes from server-65-8-181-28.mia3.r.cloudfront.net (65.8.181.28): icmp_seq=5 ttl=246 time=131 ms
```

This is my dns settings on that computer

```
  cat /etc/resolv.conf
  ## Generated by NetworkManager
  domain office.local
  search office.local
  nameserver 192.168.1.5
  nameserver 1.1.1.1
  nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Now if I do it from a windows client, **it does not work either**:

```
  ping ads2000.hw.net
  Ping ads2000.hw.net [65.8.181.28] with 32 bytes of data:
  Response from 65.8.181.28: bytes=32 time=131ms TTL=246
  Response from 65.8.181.28: bytes=32 time=131ms TTL=246
  Response from 65.8.181.28: bytes=32 time=131ms TTL=246
  Response from 65.8.181.28: bytes=32 time=131ms TTL=246
  Ping statistics for 65.8.181.28:
      Packets: sent = 4, received = 4, lost = 0
(0% lost),
  Approximate round trip times in milliseconds:
Minimum = 131ms, Maximum = 131ms, Average = 131ms
```

This is my dns settings on that computer

```
   Ethernet Ethernet Adapter:
      Specific DNS suffix for the connection. . : office.local
      DNS servers. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.5
                                          1.1.1.1
                                          8.8.8.8
```

If I remove the servers "**1.1.1.1**" and "**8.8.8.8**" from the clients, it works but from them I lose Internet (**I can not resolve names from internet domains from the clients.**)

What am I doing wrong?

I thank you in advance for your help.

**PS: Sorry for my bad English**

Comment: Your question is offtopic here as not related to programming, but may be on topic on [sf] please double check the Help there to find out what is ontopic or not and how to write great questions. Besides that, even if unrelated, any specific reason to use such an old bind version? Don't use `ping` to troubleshoot DNS problems, that is just wrong. Use a proper DNS client which is `dig` typically. Make sure to use `@` option to specify the nameserver you want to query to separate between authoritative and recursive issues.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to unsubscribe and register there.

However the browsers on the clients instead of telling me that there is nothing on localhost, they redirect me to the real page. Which it means that the name resolution is not being done according to the policy that I configured on server.  The server browser takes me to the home page since I have an Apache.
Thank you

Comment: Browsers, depending on versions and configuration, do use DoH aka DNS over HTTPS and hence will bypass your local resolver and its policies.

Comment: @patrick-mevzek
This is the correct post

 [New Post](https://serverfault.com/questions/1097058/bind9-response-policy-zone-rpz-does-not-work-on-clients) 
I find something new in relation to the listening IP address, if I use the loopback it works; if I use the IP of the network card, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
sudo systemd-resolve --flush-caches
sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved
```

Incase it didn't help,
Please add the input return from -

```
dig hw.net
```